# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object> / Querying DB causes error with assigning seperate variable to list

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

For my web app I have some variables being injected into the base/all templates with the following code:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_into_base():
    # If user is not logged in
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        # Set count to none
        count = None
        role = None

    # Else Count is set to the number of unread messages
    else: 
        count = db.session.query(message).filter(message.user_id_to == current_user.user_id).filter(message.status == False).count()
        role = db.session.query(user_society_role.role_id).filter_by(user_id=current_user.user_id).order_by(user_society_role.role_id.desc()).first().role_id

    return dict(count=count, role=role)
```

All is well until I hit a certain route that contains the line:

```
Survey.q9 = Survey.q9.split(',')
```

Which just simply splits the string into a list. It results in

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>
```

If I hard code the two db.session.query's found in inject_into_base it will run just fine, and if I comment out the .split(', ') in the route it also works fine.

I have also found assigning anything to Survey.q9 breaks my app, and ONLY on this one certain route.

Any help is much appreciated, this is my first time asking a question on here so please go easy on me :)

Answer (score -1):

Fixed my issue, turns out sqlalchemy's `autoflush` feature was breaking my app, all I had to do to fix this was add `db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={"autoflush": False})` to my `__init__.py`